# How do I get to the fourth world (Capital Cashino)?

Tags: yooka-laylee

I know the fourth (4th) world is Capital Cashino from what I read online but I don't know how to get there. I've exhausted all the entrances and skill sets I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took a long time to find this, but when exiting the third world's overworld area via the higher grappling platforms (Lizard Lash), there is a room with multiple enemies and a ground pound button that lowers a gate to the main section of the room. It's in the back of this button room (along the wall farthest from the now-opened gate). Easy to miss if you're coming from the other direction. This is what the entrance looks like from the opened gate:

[image: entrance to Capital Cashino area]

This leads to the second quiz area and from there, it's a fairly straight shot to the Capital Cashino book entrance.